# ALTER table in vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I have table in Vertica which has time_stamp:int with value Unix timestamp, I want to alter this data type from  int to `TIMESTAMPTZ`;

I tried

```
ALTER TABLE exploded_names ALTER COLUMN time_stamp SET DATA TYPE TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

But got following error

```
ROLLBACK 2353:  Cannot alter type of column "time_stamp" since it is referenced in the segmentation expression of projection "exploded_names_b0"
```

then I tried to drop that projection :

```
drop projection exploded_names_b0 CASCADE;
```

```
ROLLBACK 4122:  No up-to-date super projection left on the anchor table of projection exploded_names_b0
HINT:  Use DROP TABLE ... CASCADE to drop the anchor table and its last projection, or create a replacement super projection instead
```

I don't want to drop the table.

Comment: What is the current data type for `time_stamp`?

Comment: See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error you received is telling you that the column is used in the segmentation expression for the projection and thus can't be changed. This is a restriction for the `SET DATA TYPE` option. You can either create new superprojections and omit the column in the segmentation clause, or create a new table and projections with the new column type.

Since you mentioned that your current column is an `int` type, it won't convert to `TIMESTAMPTZ`. Here's what I would do:

**Step 1** - Set up sample data

```
CREATE TABLE public.exploded_names (
   id int,
   time_stamp int
);

INSERT INTO public.exploded_names (id, time_stamp) VALUES (1, 1403635837);

COMMIT;
```

**Step 2** - Add new column

```
ALTER TABLE public.exploded_names ADD COLUMN iso_time TIMESTAMPTZ;
```

**Step 3** - Create new super projection

We'll get the existing super projection using `SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('', 'public.exploded_names');`

```
CREATE PROJECTION public.exploded_names /*+createtype(L)*/
(
 id,
 time_stamp,
 iso_time
)
AS
 SELECT exploded_names.id,
        exploded_names.time_stamp,
        exploded_names.iso_time
 FROM public.exploded_names
 ORDER BY exploded_names.id,
          exploded_names.time_stamp
SEGMENTED BY hash(exploded_names.id, exploded_names.time_stamp) ALL NODES KSAFE 1;

SELECT MARK_DESIGN_KSAFE(1);
```

We'll need to remove the `time_stamp` column and add `iso_time` on the segmentation clause and change the name for the new superprojection:

```
CREATE PROJECTION public.exploded_names_2
(
 id,
 time_stamp,
 iso_time
)
AS
 SELECT exploded_names.id,
        exploded_names.time_stamp,
        exploded_names.iso_time
 FROM public.exploded_names
 ORDER BY exploded_names.id,
          exploded_names.time_stamp
SEGMENTED BY hash(exploded_names.id, exploded_names.iso_time) ALL NODES KSAFE 1;

SELECT MARK_DESIGN_KSAFE(1);
```

**Step 4** - Populate the new column

Here we'll update the `iso_time` column with a converted Unix timestamp and then refresh the new superprojection.

```
UPDATE public.exploded_names SET iso_time = TO_TIMESTAMP(time_stamp);

COMMIT;

SELECT REFRESH('public.exploded_names');
```

**Step 5** - Drop old superprojection

We'll need to advance the ancient history marker and then drop the old superprojection:

```
SELECT MAKE_AHM_NOW();

DROP PROJECTION public.exploded_names;
```

**Step 6** - Verify projections

Let's make sure we have the correct projection set up `SELECT GET_PROJECTIONS('public.exploded_names');`:

```
 Current system K is 1.
# of Nodes: 3.
Table public.exploded_names has 2 projections.

Projection Name: [Segmented] [Seg Cols] [# of Buddies] [Buddy Projections] [Safe] [UptoDate] [Stats]
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public.exploded_names_2_b1 [Segmented: Yes] [Seg Cols: "public.exploded_names.id", "public.exploded_names.iso_time"] [K: 1] [public.exploded_names_2_b0] [Safe: Yes] [UptoDate: Yes] [Stats: RowCounts]
public.exploded_names_2_b0 [Segmented: Yes] [Seg Cols: "public.exploded_names.id", "public.exploded_names.iso_time"] [K: 1] [public.exploded_names_2_b1] [Safe: Yes] [UptoDate: Yes] [Stats: RowCounts]
```

On a side note, if you haven't already, you should run Database Designer to get optimized projections.

Comment: Creating another projection won't make that one the superprojection....was reading the code curious if you could/knew how to do that. But I think it is defined at table creation, meaning your only choice here is to drop and re-create.